# Is there an XSS vulnerability in Stack Overflow <script>alert_("XSS");</script>

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

Note: I've edited the title because the alert was annoying me. Hopefully this will get rid of it.

Is there an XSS vulnerability in Stack Overflow?

Adding `<select>` to the title of a question causes the select box to be rendered in the Inbox on the navigation bar so perhaps script tags aren't escaped either.

[image: Screenshot of alert.]

I'm using Google Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m on Windows 8.1.

Edit and confirmation: It's not the comment replies that are causing the page to alert. It's actually the migration from SO to MetaSO.

[image: Screenshot of the source of the page.]

Final edit hopefully: Here's the original  element which made me think an issue might exist.

[image: Select box in inbox]

Comment: You should report the markup injection issue on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), as it's a network-wide problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Already migrated.

Comment: @VisioN, I was referring to MSE, not MSO ;)

Comment: And yes there is.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah, yeah :) You are right. Mods may move it if the problem will appear to be global.

Comment: Markup for this question with <script>alert("XSS");</script> appears to be encoded properly.

Comment: Whenever you get an inbox alert for this question and open the inbox on the navigation bar you'll get alerted with XSS.

Comment: @BenCr, nope, there is no alert. `<select>` elements may be rendered (I trust you on that one and didn't double-check), but definitely not `<script>`.

Comment: Would you agree that if there was an XSS issue I'd get an alert with XSS written in it? It's alerting for me. Is the HTML rendered differently for the person who asked the question?

Comment: @BenCr, I would agree, but apparently it's only occurring for you. Could you post a screenshot of what you observe?

Comment: Yeah, sure, it's done.

Comment: The question is being upvoted by someone. It might be a browser thing but someone else must be using Google Chrome. Don't you commentors also get inbox notifications for these replies?

Comment: How many tabs (30+)?!?!?!

Comment: That's just one browser window, I've got a couple open.

Comment: @BenCr no. I will if you @ me, but I upvoted the question because there's sufficient information in it to say there is a problem worth investigating, not that I got an xss alert.

Comment: @AD7six lets try this then.

Comment: You're not running extensions that might be messing with your browser?

Comment: I'm not sure how XSS comes into it, but it's certainly an injection issue if you can reproduce it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you might need to read up on XSS "XSS is a type of computer security vulnerability typically found in Web applications. XSS enables attackers to inject client-side script into Web pages viewed by other users".

Comment: I've just tried it in a new private window (which disables extensions) and it still occurs.

Comment: @BenCr: No, I think _you_ need to read up on XSS. XSS means "cross-site scripting". This is not "cross-site scripting"; it is injecting a script into the _same_ site. Quote random Wikipedia passages all you like. Also, I just confirmed no-repro in Chrome 35 Win7.

Comment: Enlighten me, what about this isn't "injecting client side script into web pages"?

Comment: Okay, if you don't like wikipedia have a look at OWASP https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) "Cross-Site Scripting attacks are a type of injection, in which malicious scripts are injected into otherwise benign and trusted web sites".

Comment: Does anyone want to create a copy of the question and then we'll be able to see if it's just the asker that sees the alert?

Comment: @BenCr perhaps add an excerpt from `view-source:meta.stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox` to the question to clarify it's nothing to to with your browser.

Comment: @AD7six Okay, good idea and I've just spotted why it's only me that's getting alerted. Picture uploaded in a second.

Comment: The text in the image is a bit small but I wanted to show the comment replies and the migration inbox item.

Comment: @BenCr: Ok, that explains it for this question, but where do you see the problem of "*Adding <select> to the title of a question causes the select box to be rendered in the Inbox on the navigation bar*"?

Comment: @Matt I'll add another image for that, it doesn't display until I dismiss the XSS alert now.

Comment: @BenCr According to your source code screencast, it seems to be parsed well for Meta inbox message and not well for SO inbox message.

Comment: This question doesn't really have an answer, I've proved there's definitely a vulnerability (but it seems it only affects the attacker at the moment). @VisioN I'd love to test it further in SO but someone else migrated my question.

Comment: @VisioN: I'm not sure what you mean? Look at line #40 in his source code screenshot; it's the "your post was migrated" inbox message which is causing this (and likely not escaped on either site) rather the other inbox message on line 21.

Comment: @Matt yeah, I've moved back to SO now and the inbox there is causing the same issue. It was always unlikely that the two sites weren't using the same code.

Comment: @Matt Maybe I used wrong wording: what I meant is that messages from SO may have parsing problems (example is this migration message), while Meta messages are escaped correctly. So the issue is either in SO messages or only in migrate message.

Comment: @VisioN: I bet lots of unicorn dollars that it's in the migrate message.

Comment: This question or rather the alert is going to ruin my enjoyment of SO. I may have to "break" the title of the question and the original <select> question to stop it from ruining my inbox.

Comment: @Matt Accepted. Then how the OP knew that there was a XSS vulnerability before posting the question on SO with a title *"Is there an XSS vulnerability in Stack Overflow ...?"*. Looks like there was another migrated question that caused this issue.

Comment: From http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/security-hole/info "Important: If you've found a security hole, do not post the vulnerability as a question. Instead, contact SE directly."

Comment: @Stijn I did contact them directly and they didn't respond.

Comment: @BenCr How long did you wait? And you thought making it public was the best idea?

Comment: @Stijn delete the question then.

Comment: I'm not sure how long I waited a couple of days. Too long for a security vulnerability. I've flagged it for attention by a mod..

Comment: Related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232423/badge-notifications-arent-properly-escaping-html, probably.

Comment: Hey Stack Exchange, you can disable inline scripts and whitelist your own domains with a `Content-Security-Policy` header. (I know, it’s not a substitute for escaping, but it really does help.)

Comment: @VisioN This question rendered a select box in my inbox which made me think that the title wasn't being escaped properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811269/first-selection-of-select-element-not-working-in-ie

Comment: @Stijn I've flagged it and it's still here. Have you flagged it? The scope of the vulnerability is fairly limited. So far the only person who's been affected by it is me. An attacker is hardly likely to want to attack themselves.

Comment: @BenCr I haven't, but a ♦ is active here in the comments now and hasn't yet deleted the question, so there's little point in flagging it again I think. Wouldn't it technically be possible to edit a question's title someone else has set a bounty for, making them vulnerable to this?

Comment: The damage potential here is *relatively* minimal as someone would have to receive a notification about a post with a script in the title (and not have that script edited out by someone else). That said, I can reproduce this... looking further.

Comment: Editing my own title now hasn't had any effect on the alert so presumably an attacker editing a question is also not going to change the inbox items which have already been created.

Comment: Amazing, reported, fixed, presumably tested and released in 3 hours. @Stijn I'm glad I created this question rather than wait for someone from support to get in touch with me.

Comment: @BenCr That's how we roll around here. :) (Credit for the actual fix goes to Jarrod Dixon.)

Answer (score -9):

No, Html that is not white listed is stripped out of the body. No Html is rendered in the title. This is the same for the notification section.

There is a [MSE post that details what Html tags are allowed in the body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).

[AD7six](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258201/is-there-an-xss-vulnerability-in-stack-overflow-scriptalertxss-script#comment35030_258201) was not able to repro this, and neither have I.

> [image]

Comment: The OP refers to the inbox of navigation bar and not to the question title or body. I could believe that (though not checked) as the navigation bar seems to be relatively new functionality, which may have bugs.

Comment: I assume the same rules apply.

Comment: It's not in the question body it's in the title.

Comment: You assume incorrectly.

Comment: Even though I might be "wrong", I'm going to leave this answer here to prove that I'm not getting this problem. I have gotten 2 notifications, both with a <script> from the question title. No XSS problems for me.

Comment: @VisioN, could you please @ reply me so we can have a second person testing this?

Comment: @gunr2171: Testing what? ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks.

Comment: @gunr2171: No `alert` here.

Comment: @gunr2171 According to the page source code posted by the OP, the tags are not escaped correctly only for SO notification messages (migration message as an example), but are parsed correctly for Meta and possibly other sites.